# Local Notification with different NSDate

Tags: iphone, ios4, uilocalnotification

In my application I am going to schedule a task to notify user at a particular date and time, for example on 31 dec. 2010 I have start time 9:00 Am and end-time 5:00 pm  , and here I have to notify user 10 minutes before 9:00 AM and  after 5:00 pm or sometime in between these times, like 2:00 pm  so  i am going to use LocalNotifications ...Am I right ? or is there any other way to achieve this .

PLease help ..

Comment: you should use local notification and for knowing how can do this,read with this link http://icodeblog.com/2010/07/29/iphone-programming-tutorial-local-notifications/

Answer (score 0):

You should use LocalNotificstion only, the thing is that you should create 3 different notification so that you can achieve the scenario